# Как выбрать номера телефонов в которых сумма первых трех цифр равна сумме последних трех?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выбрать номера телефонов (`Phone`) в которых сумма первых трех цифр равна сумме последних трех? Номер состоит из 6 цифр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Phone from Table1 where (Phone % 1000) = (Phone - (Phone % 1000)) / 1000
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что это не суммы равны, а тройки.
А так 6 сабстрингов решают проблему.

Comment: @msi - точно, прокололся

Answer (score 3):

MS SQL:

```
SELECT phone
FROM(
  SELECT phone, phone/1000 X, phone%1000 Y
  FROM Table1
)T 
WHERE X/100+X/10%10+X%10 = Y/100+Y/10%10+Y%10
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT phone
FROM(
  SELECT phone, FLOOR(phone/1000) X, phone%1000 Y
  FROM Table1
)T 
WHERE FLOOR(X/100)+FLOOR(X/10)%10+X%10 = FLOOR(Y/100)+FLOOR(Y/10)%10+Y%10
```